# JAXRS See JSON being posted from client side Entity

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

Good Evening,
I have a fairly simple web client that is posting data to another service.

I've run into some issues making the calls and the other service wants me to show exactly what JSON I am sending over.

Is there a way either to take an Entity and see what JSON JAX-RS is creating to post? Or even a way I can see what the JSON being sent over actually looks like?

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = 
webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

CustomObject foo = new CustomObject();

Entity<CustomObject> entityToPost = Entity.entity(foo, 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Response resp = invocationBuilder.post(entityToPost);
```

In this case I would like to know what foo looks like as JSON.

Edit: Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to import other libraries or tools

I'm new to JAXRS so I may be misconstruing the terms here, I apologize if that's the case.

Comment: Depending what libraries you're using, you can try Json.toJson(foo). Or you can try Gson.

Comment: @user3298823 To clarify, I'd like to know explicitly what the JSON being made by JAXRS invocationBuildr.post(entity) method looks like. I wish I had access to GSON and could just toss that over the wire, it'd make this a lot easier :)

Comment: One really simple thing to try is [http-echo-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-echo-server) or something similar and point your client to the `localhost:<port>`. The echo server dumps the request to the console. I've used this when creating SOAP and REST clients

Comment: @Phil unfortunately, I don't have the ability to use external libraries, stuck using mostly stock Java unfortunately. I edited my post to include that limitation. That being said, http-echo-server looks cool and I'll definitely add it to my bag of tricks if I need to solve this problem elsewhere!

Comment: I don't think Phil is suggesting a library, but a separate tool that you proxy your requests through. Such tools can watch the requests and responses that go back and forth. tcpmon is another.

Comment: @dbreaux I really need to get better at providing all the detail I can, I should have said external tools. I don't have access to pretty much anything other than Java and Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: That sounds very odd but if you're truly stuck, there are also online versions. Try https://requestb.in/

Comment: See if Eclipse Oxygen has tcpmon.